# Ubuntu 20.04: dataframe_image with Chrome: InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-20.04, google-chrome-headless

I have a python script that creates images (png files) from pandas dataframes. For this, I am using dataframe_image and chrome. This works fine on several machines (windows, mac, raspberry), but when I run it on a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS, I get following warnings:

```
[0106/141442.845038:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0106/141443.132682:INFO:headless_shell.cc(653)] Written to file /tmp/tmplobys34z/temp.png.
```

And 10% of the times, it just fills the memory and crashes (process gets killed).

I tried configuring selenium, but it doesn't make a difference (still having this gpu warning):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()        
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
```

And running dataframe_image with:

```
dfi.export(df,'image.png')
```

Comment: I'm also running 20.04 and running into this problem with puppeteer

Comment: I could solve the problem by downgrading Chrome to version 88.

Comment: Did you try https://simpleit.rocks/linux/ubuntu/fixing-common-google-chrome-gpu-process-error-message-in-linux/?